# Toon Monster attack drawback

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I am building a Toon Deck for my girlfriend. Toon Monsters are powerful, but their main drawback is that most cannot attack the turn they are summoned except for [Toon Dark Magician Girl](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Toon_Dark_Magician_Girl). Are there any cards that can help change that and make it to where they can attack the turn they are summoned?

Comment: Interesting question, that effect was part of their design to balance their power, but there are ways to take advantage of them ;)...

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any cards that can help change that and make it to where they can attack the turn they are summoned?

**Hardly.** The thing is that Toon monsters have that restriction *because most of them, if not all, can attack your Opponent directly.*

This condition balances their power, preventing Toon players to abuse of such relatively powerful cards, by summoning them and make a direct attack right away just like that. That delay gives your Opponent at least one chance to counter them before you start blasting their LP directly.

---

But, like Yami Yugi would say: *"Ha ha, not so fast! I activate my trap card:"* [Skill Drain](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Skill_Drain).

This is an old trick of mine that I've included in several variants of many decks (for further reading, check [Beast King Barbaros](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Beast_King_Barbaros), that and Skill Drain are a killer combo, as you can normal summon without tribute a 3k Atk monster just like that lol). Skill Drain, as you probably know, is a powerful continuous trap card that basically negates the effects of all monsters on the field (*yours also*):

> Activate by paying 1000 Life Points. The effects of all face-up monsters on the field are negated while those monsters are face-up on the field (but their effects can still be activated).

**You could be able to attack the turn you summon a Toon monster if Skill Drain is active before the summoning**, that way the moment they are summoned their "cannot attack the turn it was summoned" effect won't go off, and you will be able to conduct an attack that turn.

Of course, as Skill Drain is up their effects of attacking directly are also negated, so you can only make a direct attack if your Opponent has no monsters. However, this would suffice to what you asked, and be able to successfully attack the turn you summon them.

Also, this could work with other cards that continuously negate effects, but only if that negation applies when they are summoned. In other words, if you summon a Toon and *then* negate its effects (say, with [Breakthrough Skill](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Breakthrough_Skill)) that Toon is still not able to attack that turn, as the card came into the field (thus it's condition activated) before the negation.

Comment: I suspected you'd bring up Skill Drain. One thing I found was Pyro Clock of Destiny, but the problem though is that this trap card would have to survive a turn before it would be helpful. like you said, Skill drain might help but unfortunately the toons could no longer attack directly. So yeah I'm kind of debating whether to put that in the deck

Comment: @Therationalduelist you well could, Skill Drain is an excelent trap card, could also help you counter your opponent. And yeah, that eff was indeed planned to balance toon monsters. Another option you got (too complex IMO) is to use Skill Drain, and after summoning your toon cast Forbidden Lance on it. It will have -800 Atk, but it will be unaffected by spell/traps, so it could effectively make direct attacks while not having the restriction of having to wait a turn. This howeveray be too complicated for just one attack...

Comment: Yeah another thing that might help is Skill Drain and Shooting Star Bow Ceal. This equip card allows a monster to attack directly as long as I cut it's strength down by 1000.

Comment: @Therationalduelist yeah, that could also work